# unexpected word boundaries behavior in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re
text = 'washington d.c. columbia'
templ_1 = 'washington d.c'
templ_2 = 'washington d.c.'
print(re.sub(r'\b%s\b'%templ_1, '', text))
```

I got `. columbia` as expected

```
print(re.sub(r'\b%s\b'%templ_2, '', text))
```

I got `washington d.c. columbia` instead of `. columbia` How to fix it?

Comment: There is no _fix_ per-say. All you're doing is wrestling with what a word boundary is, which is now cleared up. Word boundary's are a little too broad in your case, what you need are whitespace boundary's instead. `(?<!\S)<your string>(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` describes a transition from word to non-word character. A `.` followed by a  is not such a transition (neither is a word character). In addition, you need to `re.escape` your strings being added to a regex, or the `.`s will match any character, not literal `.`s.

A possible fix would be:

```
print(re.sub(r'\b%s(?=\s|$)'%re.escape(templ_2), '', text))
```

using a lookahead assertion that your pattern is followed by a space or the end of string, not a word boundary (since your pattern might not end in a word character). Using `\W` instead of `\s` is also reasonable.

Comment: `\b` describes a **transition from word to non-word** character. It's a key. I thought this is means: first character after my template is **non-word**

Comment: @ElRuso: Nope. I left off the "and vice-versa" part of the definition, but to be clear, the exact meaning is "If the thing before me *was* a word character, then the thing after is *not*. If the thing before me was *not* a word character, then the thing after *must* be a word character." The line is bounded by virtual "non-word" characters for this purpose so it works roughly as expected when a word appears at either end of a line. If you have non-word, then `\b`, then non-word, the pattern will never match, because no possible string can contain the transition when there is no transition.

Answer (score 1):

A word boundary is the transition from a word to non-word, or from a non-word to a word.

In your case, you fixed that transition based on what the literal is next
to the boundary construct `\b`

In the first regex its `\bwashington d.c\b`
meaning after the `c` it expects a non-word.

In the second regex its `\bwashington d.c.\b`
and in this case, the meaning after the `.` is undefined until it finds
the character represented by a metachar dot.
In this case, it finds a literal dot `.` in the target, then the boundary
expects the next character to be a word.

So, in the second  case, the target has a space after the dot, which is
*not* a word. Thus, no match.